# With keras, how can I have an array of different models?

Tags: python, keras

I want to have many different models in an array, but I get an error:

`AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'`

My code is:

```
class INAS:
    def __init__(self, num_models=2, num_classes=10, input_shape=None):
        self.models = []
        self._num_classes = num_classes

        # self.modd = self._build_model(
        #     num_classes=num_classes, input_shape=input_shape, kernel_size=6)

        for i in range(num_models):
            mod = self._build_model(
                num_classes=num_classes, input_shape=input_shape, kernel_size=i * 3)
            self.models.append(mod)
        return

    def _build_model(self, num_classes, input_shape, kernel_size):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size), strides=(1, 1),
                         activation='relu',
                         input_shape=input_shape))

        model.add(Flatten())

        model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(
            lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

        return model

    def train(self, x_train, y_train):
        for model in self.models:
            model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, verbose=1)
```

I'm calling it with:

```
inas = INAS(input_shape=input_shape, num_classes=num_classes)

for model in inas.models:
    print(model.summary())
inas.train(x_train, y_train)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Trace:

```
  File "train.py", line 24, in <module>
    inas.train(x_train, y_train)
  File "/Users/shamoon/Sites/rowan/eonas/inas.py", line 36, in train
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, verbose=1)
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/eonas-oAqeE_OT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/eonas-oAqeE_OT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 509, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/eonas-oAqeE_OT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/eonas-oAqeE_OT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 505, in get_updates
    self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t))
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/eonas-oAqeE_OT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 973, in update
    return tf.assign(x, new_x)
  File "/Users/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/eonas-oAqeE_OT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 224, in assign
    return ref.assign(value, name=name)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace to see where the error stems from?

Comment: Which Keras and TF versions are you using?

Comment: Tensorflow 1.13. Python 3.7. Keras 2.2.4

Comment: Are you sure? The traceback is running under Python 3.6, please make sure that those are the versions that you are really using. If you use an old TensorFlow version with modern Keras version you will get such an error.

Comment: Don't you need to reset the default graph for something like that? Maybe try to look at the `tf.graph` if you can.

Comment: I updated with Python 3.7

Comment: The problem is that your `kernel_size` is **zero** in your first model. It will work if you train the second model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `kernel_size` is **zero** in your first model. The kernel of first `Conv2D` is empty.

```
print(inas.models[0].layers[0].get_weights()[0].shape)
print(inas.models[1].layers[0].get_weights()[0].shape)

# print
(0, 0, 3, 32)
(3, 3, 3, 32)
```

It will work if you train the second model.